# Passing highcharts object to web worker

Tags: javascript, multithreading, charts, highcharts, web-worker

I am building a real-time visualisation tool for some PC hosts, using the highcharts library. Using websocket, the web application receives data and update the charts (11 charts per web application, per host). The javascript code is in one single file and that causes the browser to freeze at some point, or just some considerable latency.

After googling, i read about web workers, and thought of trying it to optimize. So I came up with 02 javascript files:

- The first one (**Main thread**) initialising UI and charts etc...
- The second one (**worker**) supposed to listen to websocket, and update the charts.

Since the charts are created in the main thread (because that's where i can acces the DOM and choose charts' container), when i try to transfer the charts to the worker i get the `DATA_CLONE_ERR` error as follows:

```
DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned.
```

Below is the part of the script triggering the code, precisely at the postmessage() part:

```
var charts_list = []; //charts    
function initAllCharts(host_i, l_id, pos){
var chart_i;
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  if (i < 4){
    chart_i = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: l_id + '_graph'+i,
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift'                                    
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: true
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
        spline: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150,
        maxZoom: 20 * 1000
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        minPadding: 0.2,
        maxPadding: 0.2,
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: []
      }]
    });
  }else{
    chart_i = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: l_id + '_histogram'+i,
        type: 'column',   
        zoomType: 'xy',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift'
      },
      title: {
        text: '',
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: '',
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      tooltip: {},
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          pointPadding: 0,
          groupPadding: 0,
          borderWidth: 0.5,
        }
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: ''
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: ''
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Random Data',
        data: []
      }],
    });
  }
  charts_list.push(chart_i);
  chart_i = {};
}
//Post to worker
toChartsWorker = {"charts_list":charts_list};
chartsDataWorker.postMessage(toChartsWorker);

return chart_i;
```

}

So far, that's the only approach i have. Could you please help me out ? Do you see another way of doing ?

Comment: Can you post the code that's triggering the error?

Comment: @AlejandroC. I added it!

Comment: The error is explained here [Things that don't work with structured clones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) Updating the chart updates dom - web worker does not have access to the dom. You should investigate with the profiler which part of the code causes latency and maybe load your charts in chunks.